Next.js useDebouncedCallback does not seem to delay the request
I am following the Next.js tutorial. Currently I am stuck on this page:
https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-search-and-pagination
After a thorough web search with no clear answer, I would like to consult you. Thanks.


  function handleSearch(term: string) {
    const handleSearch = useDebouncedCallback((term) => {
      console.log(`Searching... ${term}`);
      const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
      if (term) {
        params.set('query', term);
      } else {
        params.delete('query');
      }
      replace(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`);
    }, 300); 
  }



The idea is that whatever is filled into the input field, is passed on as a parameter to the url and in turn used to search in the database. Without the useDebouncedCallback function the database will be queried after each typed letter. The useDebouncedCallback should delay the database query until 300ms after the user stops typing.
The tutorial explains that in the console log, before the useDebouncedCallback function is added, the the output for a search for the name 'Emil' would be this:
Searching... E
Searching... Em
Searching... Emi
Searching... Emil

And after adding the useDebouncedCallback function, the output for typing 'Emil' would only display the whole search term, like so:
Searching... Emil

However, my console still displays the letter-by-letter output. The url search parameter also updates after each letter and not 300ms after the final letter. Thus still querying the database after each letter.
My question is: Is there an error in this code (which is directly copied from the tutorial) or is this expected behavior? Am I misunderstanding something?

you are wrapping the debounce function with other function with same name.. you need to remove the outer function to work as u expected..

Yes, this indeed is the problem. If you make an answer of this, I will accept it.


This function will wrap the contents of handleSearch, and only run the code after a specific time once the user has stopped typing (300ms).

This is from the documentation you provided. This code only prevents the rapid re running of the function inside, if you type slower than 300ms per character you will see each letter.
[EDIT]
Posting my comment below so that it is included in the answer
Here is a minimal working example for you, I have verified the behavior Working Example

Thank you for the fast response. I have also tested this with 3000ms and still the letters in console and query in url are updated immediately instead of after 3 seconds. That is why it seems that the function is not doing anything. Do you have any other ideas?

Here is a minimal working example for you, I have verified the behavior
[https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/serene-roman-dfshjx?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A18%2C1] ( Working Example )

Yes that does indeed work. Can you edit your answer so I can accept it as solution?
